# Swift Xcode NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I just started with iPhone development and thanks to the many out there I got a simple application working. I was using the following code to pull data from a mysql database. The code is in a commonfun.swift file where I hold all functions and it is call from various swift file  when needed. Due to communication links it will try for 30 seconds.

It all work great. It synchronized because It load the data into a array at the "end" of the function and "return" to the calling swift file.

SAMPLE CODE FOLLOWS:

```
 import UIKit
 class commonfunc
 {
     var result1: [String] = [];

 func DB_To_Array_Swift(whattoget: String,  inout jsondata: NSDictionary)
  ... set up stuff
  ... call php to get data
 while while_exit == "NO"
    {
        number_of_retries = number_of_retries + 1
        if number_of_retries > 30
        {
            break
        }
        do
        {
            urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
            while_exit = "YES"
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            tmperror = error
            while_exit = "NO"
            sleep(1)
        }
    }
... load data into an array and return to calling swift file.
```

Works great! and gets called from various swift files with different criteria.

Now it says NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest is depreciated.

I tried to replace it with NSURLSession.sharedSession() but it run async and return to the main swift file.

i tried to replace it with below. but.....

```
 while while_exit == "NO"
    {
        number_of_retries = number_of_retries + 1
        if number_of_retries > 30
        {
            while_exit == "YES"
            break
        }
            let session =   NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            {
                (
                let urldata, let response, let error) in
                if error != nil
                {
                    tmperror = error!
                    while_exit = "NO"
                    sleep(1)
                }
                let dataString = NSString(data: urldata!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString) 

                while_exit = "YES"
            }
            print("\n here5")
            task.resume()
            print("\n here6")

    }
    while while_exit == "NO"
    {
        sleep(1)
    }
```

I there a way to make it look sync in the commonfunc.swift

thanks

Comment: `sleep` is very bad, synchronous networking is very bad. There is always a way to use asynchronous patterns. In your case use `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionDataTask` and implement the delegate methods. In `didCompleteWithError` either start a timer and rerun the task on error or create the string from the received data and continue *load data into an array and return to calling swift file*.

Answer (score 0):

var data: NSData? = nil
        let semaphore: dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            taskData, _, error -> () in
            data = taskData
            if data == nil, let error = error {print(error)}
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        })
        task.resume()
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        return data

Comment: Semaphores are bad, too.

Comment: bad bad bad ... so what is your suggestion if any.

Comment: See my suggestion in the other comment.